# What do the gold stars do?

Tags: tiny-wings

What do the gold stars do in Tiny Wings?

Is it worth trying to collect them (i.e. effecting the sun) or do they merely give a higher score?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are worth 3 points, and may count towards certain objectives which "upgrades your nest" (increases your point multiplier).

If you don't care about points and just distance, they have no effect.